# how to search for every uppercase character inside some string and replace it

Tags: php, arrays, string

what i'm trying to make a `function` to change the `camelcase` variables like `"myFullName"` to be readable version. for example 
if i have varible like this

```
$label = "myFullName" 

<!-- expected output is -->

$label = "my full name" ;
```

Comment: using [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) is the best way to do it

Comment: will be `camelCase` the pattern to convert to `camel case`. insert an space before every uppercase and lowercase the letter?

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but ***you need to help yourself first. :-)*** After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Answer (score 3):

A different approach to REGEX will be to iterate over the word and check if there is an uppercase letter, insert an space before and lowercase the letter

```
$label = 'myFullName';

$new_word='';

for($i=0, $n=strlen($label); $i<$n; $i++){

     $new_word .= strtoupper($label[$i]) == $label[$i] 
        ? ' '.strtolower($label[$i]) 
        : $label[$i];
}

echo $new_word;

//Output
//my full name
```

Comment: Nice one. You can also do it in one line: `for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($label); $i++) (ctype_upper($label[$i]) ? $new_word .= " " . strtolower($label[$i]) : $new_word .= $label[$i]);`